# Exposed dropdown menu does not expand when clicked

Tags: java, android, material-design, material-components-android

I'm trying to implement an [**Exposed dropdown menu**](https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus) with a `TextInputLayout` and an `AutoCompleteTextView`. I'm on Android SDK 12 (API Level 31).

Following virtually every tutorial on the internet (including Google's own documentation), my XML looks like this:

```xml
<!-- layoutAbc.xml -->
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutAbc"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/inputAbc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/abc"
        android:inputType="none" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```xml
<!-- list_item.xml -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1" />
```

And the java code, which runs from `onCreateView()`:

```java
String[] inputs = new String[] { "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.component_list_item, inputs);
c.inputFrequency.setAdapter(adapter);
c.inputFrequency.setText("Option 1", false);
```

I can see that the default value of the `AutoCompleteTextView` is set to **"Option 1"** perfectly fine: [image: An input field with the value Option 1]

However, when I click the input, **nothing happens**. I never see the expanded dropdown menu with **"Option 2"** and **"Option 3"**. I looked around a lot but I couldn't find anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I had the following attributes on my `TextInputLayout`:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
    app:endIconMode="custom">
...
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The documentation made it seem like it doesn't really matter what other attributes exist on the `TextInputLayout`, which is clearly not the case. If you don't have this particular issue, I suggest you remove every custom attribute you have (start with the example line by line and make sure it works) and then add your attributes back one by one.

Comment: Correct!, I have removed endIconMode = "custom" and it's working perfectly.